# How do I get a number that is inserted into a single string?

Tags: python, string

I have a file of about 2000 lines, each with, value="n". There's no spaces in-between the characters, the "" are present, and the numbers vary in length.

I assume that since value=" is constant throughout I can start from the next position after the " and grab everything until I reach the next "

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a more explicit example of what you are dealing with? And an exact output you expect from that sample? More importantly, can you please show your own code attempt at this and explain what is currently not working?

Comment: @Hawkeyes, there are literally endless ways to interpret your question, a line or two of input would be more helpful than the whole description

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for.

```
with open("input.txt") as fp:
    result = [int(line.split('"')[1]) for line in fp]
print result
```